# Replicate to a test network, AD loses trust and network location

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a separate VMware ESX 5.5 server that we use as a test environment, where we replicate production machines. It runs replicated VMs on a vSwitch that is physically separated from the production network. Last month, we used Veeam to copy VMs to the server and simulate production, for the purpose of upgrading AD from 2008R2 to 2012R2. This worked very well, and so we upgraded production with minimal trouble. I should say that last month, this test environment had NO internet access, so the testing was imperfect in that minor way, but served us well regardless.

This month, we introduced an Internet connection on a completely separate cable modem line to the mock-production vLan on the test ESX server, so that we could do more testing (for an application's upgrade which uses IIS and SQL services) but see real connectivity from clients coming across the Internet. So I have replicated servers handling DC's, DNS, Certificate Services, IIS, and SQL and even Network Policy even though I don't think that plays a hand here. The Internet connection works, but I now see that for about an hour or so after replicating the VMs from production, the network location changes from lss.local to Public. Also, at no point is the test IIS server able to serve out a site, and I see that domain trust relationships are now broken, and recreating them fails every time. Network Location Awareness sets the locations at Public, and setting them manually (via local policy) to Private. They can query DNS successfully, and I am rather stymied as to why the introduction of an internet connection would break all NLA and all secure channels, where it did not behave like this when the Internet had no presence. Meanwhile, servers in production carry on happily, so I don't worry about cross-contamination.

So in short, all these issues now come about from the presence of a new route online OR the replication of a freshly-upgraded AD 2012R2 domain. I suspect NLA has a hand in the trouble here. Where would you start looking to pinpoint the cause of the change in network location?

Comment: `They can query DNS successfully` - They can query what specifically? What DNS servers do these domain members use?

Comment: Hi Joe, they can query AD DNS servers (located on domain controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my case I had my host still under the control of production vCenter, and not either on its own or as a member of a different vCenter datacenter. This made it so that vCenter was giving out different MACs to the VMs